# table row not append to division table through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hello i am trying to add table in division through javascript when date is change...data coming from database and adding to table.

but the problem is that table row is not generating.

here is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DateWiseData(DateTime SelectedDate)
    {
        var Dw = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var idparam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "date",
            Value = SelectedDate
        };
        var waxlist = Db.Database.SqlQuery<PRCWax>("exec sp_PRCWax_Get_Date @date", idparam).ToList();
        return Json(waxlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

here is my javascript

```
 $("#DT").on("change", function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DateWiseData", "ProcessWax")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'SelectedDate': selectedValue }),
                success: function (waxlist) {
                    if (Object.keys(waxlist).length > 0) {
                        $('#detailtbl').append('<div class="card">' +
                                                   '<div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">' +
                                                   '<div class="card-icon"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>' +
                                                   '</div><h4 class="card-title">DataTables.net</h4></div>' +
                                                   '<div class="card-body">' +
                                                   '<div class="toolbar"><!-- Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar --></div>' +
                                                   '<div class="material-datatables">' +
                                                   '<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">' +
                                                   '<thead>' +
                                                   '<tr>' +
                                                   '<th>PRC no</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Die No</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Description</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Metal</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Qty</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Reject Qty</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Total Weight</th>' +
                                                   '<th>Username</th>' +
                                                   '</tr>' +
                                                   '</thead>' +
                                                   '<tbody>' +
                                               waxlist.forEach(function (data) {
                                                   alert('Successfully done.');
                                                   '<tr>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.MOULDCODE + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.DESCRIPTION + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.METALNAME + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.QTY1 + data.QTY2 + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.REJECTQTY1 + data.REJECTQTY2 + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                                                   '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                                                   '</tr>'
                                               }),
                                                   +'</tbody>' +
                                                   '</table>' +
                                                   '</div>' +
                                                   '</div>' +
                                                   '</div>');
                    }
                },
                //error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
            });
        });
```

this is my waxlist structure which is shown in console
[Waxlist structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbxhF.png)

running this code "Successfully done" alert is invoke till data have value..but after table row not generate...

Where i am wrong in code..please tell me how to solve this.?

Comment: Can you try debugging your code and check what is coming inside "data"?

Comment: in waxlist value coming from database in list format and in data present row showing with value

Comment: Can you please post your "waxlist" structure (hardcoded value)?

Comment: no..my problem is not solve ....i want to generate table row from data..

Comment: that is not generating .....u see alert in script ...it is invoke but after alert code is not perform..i think so...

Comment: Suppose in data 2 records are coming from database than it will generate 2 table row ...

Comment: I got the context you are trying to do. The only thing which could be out of place is waxList. so i request you to share waxList structure.

Comment: ok i share the structure of waxlist which will show in console..and update my question

Comment: @Charu Maheshwari  ..i update the question and share structure of waxlist

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
 var htmlData = "";
        htmlData += '<div class="card">' +
            '<div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">' +
            '<div class="card-icon"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>' +
            '</div><h4 class="card-title">DataTables.net</h4></div>' +
            '<div class="card-body">' +
            '<div class="toolbar"><!-- Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar --></div>' +
            '<div class="material-datatables">' +
            '<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th>PRC no</th>' +
            '<th>Die No</th>' +
            '<th>Description</th>' +
            '<th>Metal</th>' +
            '<th>Qty</th>' +
            '<th>Reject Qty</th>' +
            '<th>Total Weight</th>' +
            '<th>Username</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</thead>' +
            '<tbody>';
        waxlist.forEach(function (data) {

            htmlData += '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.MOULDCODE + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.DESCRIPTION + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.METALNAME + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.QTY1 + data.QTY2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.REJECTQTY1 + data.REJECTQTY2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
        });

        htmlData += '</tbody>' +
            '</table>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        $("#detailtbl").append(htmlData);
```